# Issue using toupper function in c++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment for my c++ class where I must use cstring for strings.

The assignment is supposed to be a program that accepts input from the user for the first and the last name. Then the program has to convert the first letter of the first name to a Uppercase. As well convert the last letter of the last name to Uppercase. I was able to find a way to convert the first letter of the first name to uppercase; however couldn't replace the lowercase letter with the upper case letter. In addition, couldn't figure out how to capitalize the last letter of the last name.

This is the part of the code related to the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    //Variable Declaration
    char firstName[50];
    char secondName[50];
    char second[50];
    char firstLetter;
    int result;
    int charLength;

//Program Header
    cout << "\t\t>>>>>>>> Welcome to The Bog Office of Names <<<<<<<<";

        cout << "\nEnter first name: ";
        cin >> firstName;
        cout << "\nEnter second name: ";
        cin >> secondName;

            firstLetter= toupper(secondName[0]);
            firstLetter = toupper(firstLetter);

            cout << "\nFormatted name: " << secondName << " " << firstName;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about, like, assigning the uppercased letter value back to the first position of the string?

Comment: Why are you calling `toupper` on the letter that you already converted to uppercase on the previous line?

Comment: `secondName[0]` is the first letter of the last name. Your assignment said to do the **last** letter of the last name, didn't it?

Comment: General comments. Instead of  arrays of `char` use `std::string`. When calling the C library's `toupper` note the argument must be non-negative or `EOF`, i.e. you should cast it to `unsigned char`, unless you restrict yourself to ASCII, where there are no negative values. Using `char` based text, narrow text, the code is restricted to single-byte character sets, e.g. no UTF-8. In order to deal with Unicode you need to use wide text, e.g. `wchar_t` based text. And corresponding streams. And for that, in Windows, better configure those streams to deal correctly with Windows console i/o.

Comment: Cheers,, I thought about reassigning but I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Barmar,, because the first time it didn't convert to uppercase when I ran the code, so I did it again.

Comment: Barmar, well the assignment as well require that the program decide's, which name becomes the first name based on alphabetical order. The code above is apart of an if statement

Comment: Thank so, much guys I will try to figure something out using your notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just storing uppercase letter to `firstLetter` which is not helping:

```
int len=strlen(secondName);
firstName[0] = toupper(firstName[0]);
```

For accessing last letter use `len-1` as `len='\0'`

```
secondName[len-1] = toupper(secondName[len-1]);  //notice len-1
```

Comment: Thank you wrangler this worked like a charm for capitalizing the last letter!    Thank all guys I think, I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
firstName[0] = toupper(firstName[0]);
secondName[0] = toupper(secondName[0]);
secondName[strlen(secondName)-1] = toupper(secondName[strlen(secondName)-1]);
```